# Checkmarx: Improper Exception Handling with Mybatis resultMap in Java

Tags: java, security, mybatis, checkmarx

My project was scanned by Checkmarx, and all the Mybatis xml files show the same risk: **Improper Exception Handling**.

The report says that every resultMap code like this `<resultMap id="resultMap" type="com.example.Test">` may throw expected exceptions, and should be wrapped in a try-catch block.

But we can't write try-catch in xml files. We've done exception handling everywhere we use the sql code, but still get the same result.

Is there anyway to prevent Checkmarx showing this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not seem vulnerable. A quick analysis shows a Checkmarx issue with the interpretation of `MyBatis` and `iBatis`.

You can mark it as "Not Exploitable" and report the False Positive to Checkmarx.

Comment: The Checkmarx reports were provided by our client. They are unwilling to mark vulnerability as "Not Exploitable" because they have to write reports to their director. But maybe it's the only way to resolve this problem... Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> If you determine that a vulnerability is a false positive, then you should mark it as Not Exploitable. This will cause Checkmarx to stop showing this vulnerability in subsequent scans within this Application.

taken from here: https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/GO/pages/1986658305/SAST+Results+Review+Methodology

Comment: The Checkmarx reports were provided by our client. They are unwilling to mark vulnerability as "Not Exploitable" because they have to write reports to their director. But maybe it's the only way to resolve this problem... Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It's not whether the issue is "not exploitable", it's whether the issue is a false positive. SAST tools tend to produce a lot of noise (false positive rate is high; more than 50% off all issues can be like this). Get used to it. Your superiors should as well.